# Converting UTF-8 to ASCII in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding

I am writing a console application, which reads emails from different email boxes and processes through them. Emails are received from various automated systems. The email messages are logged and/or sent forward.

The problem is that some emails are encoded in UTF-8 and transfer-encoded in quoted-printable which messes up special characters (mainly ä,ö and å). I have not found any solution to convert them in readable format.

For example "ä" in quoted-printable is "=C3=A4". Using a normal conversion methods the result is "Ã¤" (gibberish).

I shamelessly ripped this example conversion table from here: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5315363

```
char   codepoint          UTF-8 encoding                 as Latin-1

ä      11100100 = E4      11000011 10100100 = C3 A4      Ã¤ = \u00C3\u00A4
å      11100101 = E5      11000011 10100101 = C3 A5      Ã¥ = \u00C3\u00A5
ö      11110110 = F6      11000011 10110110 = C3 B6      Ã¶ = \u00C3\u00B6

Ä      11000100 = C4      11000011 10000100 = C3 84      Ã? = \u00C3\u0084
Å      11000101 = C5      11000011 10000101 = C3 85      Ã? = \u00C3\u0085
Ö      11010110 = D6      11000011 10010110 = C3 96      Ã? = \u00C3\u0096
```

So how do I get the real codepoint from UTF-8 value? I'd rather not use any external libraries. Besides I've tried a couple already and they failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the effects you describe, I guess you get the emails by directly connectiong to POP3 mail boxes? If so, then you get the emails in their **raw** form and most of those mails will most probably be in the MIME format.

MIME ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) has a good overview) is a rather large and complex standard and implementing a MIME parser that reliably handles all the cases you want to have covered could very well take you a few weeks.

I'd therefore consider using a thrid-party MIME library that does the job for you.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not completely sure, but this might do the trick:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString))
```

I'm not on my computer right now so I can't test it, but I'll try it later.

Comment: you get an ASCII string with 'strange' characters replaced by `??`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert from UTF-8 to Latin1 - after doing the quoted-printable conversion.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66sschk1.aspx looks promising.